# Can't mass-assign protected attributes attr_accessor and attr_accessible

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2

in `rails 2.3.11`, I have below in model

```
attr_accessor :person_id
```

and in controller

```
@project.person_id = current_user.id
```

now, I am converting this in `rails 3.2.11` and I am getting

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: person_id
```

so I changed in model, I removed `:person_id` from `attr_accessor` and add below line

```
attr_accessible :person_id
```

but I am uisng person_id in controller, here it is

```
@project.person_id = current_user.id
```

I am getting this now

```
NoMethodError in ProjectsController#create

undefined method `person_id=' for #<Project:0x19cc51a>
```

any idea or help, How can I fix this? How can I handle both attr_accessor & attr_accessible?

Comment: put them in both  `attr_accessible :person_id` ; `attr_accessor :person_id`

Comment: @ShawnBalestracci if I am placing both `attr_accessible :person_id` ; `attr_accessor :person_id`, I am getting `Can't mass-assign protected attributes: person_id`

Comment: The mass assignment error is not coming from this line: `@project.person_id = current_user.id`, since this is not mass-assignment.

Comment: @Arjan yes, you are right, I am getting because I used that person_id in model number of places.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`attr_accessor :person_id` and `attr_accessible :person_id` are not the same.

[attr_accessor](http://ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Module.html#method-i-attr_accessor) is the **Ruby** method. In short its shortcut for methods:

```
def person_id
  @person_id
end

def person_id=(value)
  @person_id = value
end
```

[attr_accessible](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) is the **Rails** method. Which gets list of attributes allowed to be mass-assigned. You can read about [here](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/security.html#mass-assignment).

Thus in your case you need both of them.

```
attr_accessor :person_id
attr_accessible :person_id
```

Comment: if I am placing both attr_accessible :person_id ; attr_accessor :person_id, I am getting Can't mass-assign protected attributes: person_id

Comment: Hm. check the `config.active_record.whitelist_attributes = true` in your `application.rb`. And try to play with `true`/`false` then