# Last version of activerecord-reputation-system bug?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, twitter

i'm trying to use but this error persist,
i'm using rails 3

```
Can't mass-assign protected attributes: reputation_name, target_id, target_type, aggregated_by
```

Comment: thank's nu for your interest, well yes but none of the gem

Comment: Did you look this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429582/cant-mass-assign-protected-attributes-attr-accessor-and-attr-accessible might help